# making pySFML work on linux

Tags: python, linux, sfml

This might be stupid question, but I am not sure what do to.
Basically I have install sfml-dev (2.3.2) and later python-sfml(2.2) and cython(0.23.4) because by my understanding python-sfml is "not a pure python library. Rather, it is a set of extensions that provide a Pythonic API around a C++ library. As such, every PySFML object is really a wrapped C++ object which can be manipulated through Python methods".

Now I have wrote a small program (displaying a window) in python, but I get error 'module' object has no attribute 'RenderWindow'.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

kk, I managed to fix it.
You need to have these two lines at the beginning of the code when

```
    import sfml as sf 
    from sfml import sf
    #your code in python using the SFML library
```